# Elixir: How to count urls in a string

Tags: regex, string, count, elixir

Suppose I have a string:

```
content = "Please visit https://www.google.com...\nOr visit http://my.website.io\nhttp://myfriends.website.com\nOr https://www.myneigborsite.com, http://visit.me.com"
```

There are 5 urls in the string.

How do i count the urls using syntax?

I have tried using `Regex.scan/2 |> Enum.count/1`, or `String.split/2 |> Enum.count/1` <- with regex but i always get wrong output.

I have also tried every http/https regex I found in the internet, but still I can't get the correct output.

Here's one that I've tried.

```
iex> content
...> |> String.split(~r/^(https?):\/\/[^\s$.?#].[^\s]*$/)
...> |> Enum.count()
...> |> Kernel.-(1)
-1
```

Another one with the same regex..

```
iex> Regex.scan(~r/^(https?):\/\/[^\s$.?#].[^\s]*$/, content) |> Enum.count()
0
```

but when I check if the regex matches some of the urls

```
iex> Regex.match?(~r/^(https?):\/\/[^\s$.?#].[^\s]*$/, "https://www.google.com")
true
iex(48)> Regex.match?(~r/^(https?):\/\/[^\s$.?#].[^\s]*$/, "http://my.website.io")
true
```

It does match.
I can't figure out what's the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only *count* urls, which means you don’t need an overcomplicated regular expression.

```rb
~r|https?://[\w.-]+|
|> Regex.scan(content)
|> Enum.count()
#⇒ 5
```

---

Your attempts failed because you put `$`, the EOL-matcher in the expressions, which is obviously not matched when the URL is not terminating the string.

Comment: Wow, that was fast answer!
Thank you for pointing out the `$` in regex.